# How can I stop the new line from adding a space between my list items in HTML

Tags: html

I have the following HTML;

```
li 
{
    list-style: none;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
...
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

When I add the list items on their own line they appear with a horizontal space between them, but when I do it as;

```
<li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 2</li>
```

they dont.

Is there anyway to stop the new line from showing up as the blank space, or do I need to use a negative margin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason there is space between them is because there is space between them. :-)

You can float the `li`'s to the left and that'll get rid of it:

```
li { float: left; }
```

Ciao!

Comment: To clarify the "...because there is space between them...":

HTML will collapse all white-space into a single space element between words or elements.  It will not remove all white-space altogether or else things would be a mess. :-)

Comment: This is good but is there any other solution without using float?

Answer (score 31):

You can remove that space by using HTML comments:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li><!--
--><li>Item 2</li><!--
--><li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

There is also a css property supported by newer browsers, but I can't remember what it's called (this is a hard search query).

Comment: This is a very unique alternative to having disorganize code like everyone suggests.

Comment: You may be referring to [`text-space-collapse: discard;`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-4/#propdef-text-space-collapse) which has not been implemented in any browsers yet.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid those spaces you can use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) css property

```
ul {
    display: flex;
}
```

See [example](https://jsbin.com/boyiyacado/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: this makes it not inline for me, so this solution doesn't work all the time

Answer (score 4):

That space is correct with inline content. You have two alternatives:

1. Put them on the same line like you're doing; or
2. Use floats.

For example:

```
ul { overflow: hidden; }
li { float: left; border: solid 1px blue; margin: 0px; }
```

The `overflow: hidden` ensures the containing `<ul>` won't collapse. Compare the difference with and without it if you add a red border to the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `float` property to li's and use [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or atleast:

```
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```