# Why the space between divs when using display: inline-block

Tags: css

Why is an empty space between divs when using `display: inline-block`, like in this example: http://jsbin.com/IhULuZO/1/edit.

I know I can use `float:left`, but I want to get rid of the empty space without floating elements if possible.

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241696/how-to-get-rid-of-space-between-divs-when-display-inline-block-and-stacked-horiz) can help you..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the indentation of your code technically is a bunch of whitespace.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, of course! Thanks for opening my eyes :D

Answer (score 2):

there is that space between those divs to make them more readable.
To delete these spaces, comment all the space in html like this :

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div><!--
    --><div class="child"></div><!--
    --><div class="child"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you have written `.child` divs on separate lines. If you write them on same line, extra space will be removed.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the space between  *.child* divs and Code Should Appear Like these.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div>
 </div>
```