# Divs suddenly getting margins and incosistent jQuery behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two questions:

1. I have an assignment, where I populate a square grid with a lot of small square divs (think pixels). They should not have any margins - and they don't, as long as there are no more of them than 51 in a row. Then suddenly they get margins, and overflow my grid (a wrapper div). I've reset all the margins in the css to 0, and even used a negative margin, and it still happens. Why is that?
2. Second thing is some inconsistency when calling a JS function on a button click. It goes like this: when I use jQuery to bind that function to a button (the `on()` function), it works in JSfiddle, but IT DOES NOT WORK in the browser (I use chromium). I have to use `onclick` in the button's html tags for it to work. Again, why is that?

Here's the code parts I think could be the problem:

```
function reset() {
var new_size = prompt('Enter a new amount of squares in a row');
populate(new_size);
}

$('#reset').on('click', function () {
    reset();
})
```

This should make the reset work on the button, and it does work in jsfiddle, but not in the browser.

This works for the browser:

```
<input id="reset" onclick='reset();' type="submit" value="Reset">
```

Here's some css:

```
* {
margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.square {
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}
```

When I tried to reset margins to 0, it didn't work either, I had to use negative one.

Thanks.

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Comment: Your event that you're adding to reset should be in document.ready(), if not, the element may not exist yet to add the event to.

Comment: I dodn't want to post the code here, because I would probably have to post the whole css, html and JS script, so I thought that would take too much place. And on jsFiddle you can see how it all works at once. My bad, though.

Comment: font-size: 0;  add this to your wrapper. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241696/how-to-get-rid-of-space-between-divs-when-display-inline-block-and-stacked-horiz

Comment: It seems to have helped, but why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this: putting a non-breaking-space ( ) in the divs.... so they are not empty.

```
$('.wrapper').append("<div class='square'>&nbsp;</div>");
```

It works...

I am not sure why... I think is a rendering problem in some browsers like IE...

Comment: I think this did nothing for me. Which part did you mean it would work on?