# Elements inside scroller not aligning although numbers are correct

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple user-controlled carousel, but with each scroll the currently-displayed section comes out of alignment by about 4.5px.

It works by collecting all the direct ancestor `<section>` tags inside the parent container it has hooked onto, setting `display: inline-block` on each `<section>` and making the width of each `<section>` the same.

The scrolling is achieved by setting the `<section>` container's `margin-left` property to negative N * W, where N is the number of `<section>` tags scrolled and W is the width of each `<section>`.

The `padding` and `margin` properties of the `<section>` tags and the container have been set to 0.

What could be causing this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/835kxb2w/ - I have added borders to the `<section>` tags to make the issue more apparent.

Also, in what I think is a related issue (to do with whitespace leftover from templates?), the last section breaks onto a new line. This is despite the `<section>` container being the exactly N * W pixels wide.

Thanks

Comment: `inline-block` will render any spaces between your tags as spaces on the page, line-breaks included. You can avoid this by using `float` instead, by removing any spaces/line-breaks in your code, or by wrapping it in a container with `font-size: 0px;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `font-size: 0;` to the `.profileService_profileDescriptors` class (and remove the border style from `.beautySection`).

[Reasoning here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241696/how-to-get-rid-of-space-between-divs-when-display-inline-block-and-stacked-horiz)