# don't want whitespace to occur when text is too long and i got to enter

Tags: html, laravel, text, whitespace, laravel-blade

Is there any way when your text is too long - and you break it up with new lines - to not have whitespace happen? What I need is three values to be joint without whitespace in between.

```
<div style='font-size:100%; color:blue'>
    {{ $record->m_pk_address_line1 }}
    {{ $record->m_pk_address_line2 }}
    {{ $record->m_pk_address_line3 }}
</div>
```

Without entering new line, it'll be too long even if they can be joined together.

```
<div style='font-size:100%; color:blue'>{{ $record->m_pk_address_line1 }}{{ $record->m_pk_address_line2 }}{{ $record->m_pk_address_line3 }}</div>
```

Is there no standard way of going about this without resorting to tricks? What do people do when their code is too long and they need to break it up into new lines but they don't want the whitespace that comes with it?

Comment: Can you expected result example?

Comment: Here's a unique idea I found elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24000693/1786065 . Outside of that you're potentially looking at some CSS rules to remove the whitespace.

Comment: @GovindSamrow do you mean post the expected results? e.g MynameisBen vs. My name is Ben

Comment: Yes, My name is Ben is expected result?

Comment: @GovindSamrow My name is Ben for the first code and MynameisBen for the second code. I need it to be like the second code but my code is too long and I need to break it up with enters.

Comment: @BenKao Simply Concatenate all these items

Answer (score 1):

You could make an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in the model of `$record`

```
public function getFullAddressAttribute($value)
{
    return $record->m_pk_address_line1 . $record->m_pk_address_line2 . $record->m_pk_address_line3;
}
```

and use that in your views like this

```
$record->full_address;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two tricks to avoid whitespace, the first is html comments:

```
<div style='font-size:100%; color:blue'>
     {{ $record->m_pk_address_line1 }}<!--
  -->{{ $record->m_pk_address_line2 }}<!--
  -->{{ $record->m_pk_address_line3 }}
</div>
```

the second is font-size: 0

```
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.container > * {
  font-size: 1rem; /** or whatever suits your needs **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing whitespaces use

```
$string= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);

<div style='font-size:100%; color:blue'>
    {{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $record->m_pk_address_line1 }}
    {{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $record->m_pk_address_line1 }}
    {{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $record->m_pk_address_line1 }}
</div>
```

Comment: The whitespaces are resultant of the newlines, this would only affect the input from `m_pk_*`

Answer (score 0):

**Concatenate all three items:**

```
<div style='font-size:100%; color:blue'>
    {{ $record->m_pk_address_line1.$record->m_pk_address_line2.$record->m_pk_address_line3 }}
</div>
```